# Вывод последовательности чисел

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-3.6, python-2.7

Объясните пожалуйста, почему в этом коде выполняется

> if a > c:

Если вводить числа 9, 5, 15? А так же выполняется и это условие:

> if b > c:

То есть ответ я получаю такой

9

5

15

9 15 5

5 15 9

Как он входит во второй if если a < c, а так же как он входит в третий if если b < c

```
a = input ()
b = input ()
c = input ()

if a > b:
    if a > c:
        print (a, c, b)
    else:
        print (c, a, b)

if b > c:
    print (b, c, a)
else:
    print (c, b, a)}
```

Comment: А Вы точно вводите числа, а не строки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Введённые значения нужно привести к числам `a = int(input())`

Независимо от этого, логика везде нарушена.

`if b > c` выполняется независимо от первого.
И возможных исходов должно быть 6, а не 4

```
if A > B:
       if A > C:
              if B > C:
                    A B C
              else:
                    A C B  
        else:    
            C A B
else:
      if B > C:
             if C > A:
                    B C A
             else:
                    B A C
      else:
          C B A
```

Comment: В вашем варианте тоже не работает

Comment: Вот как получается
9
5
15
9 5 15

Comment: Ввод 9 5 15 вывод 9 5 15

Comment: В моём варианте работает, а Вашу интерпретацию я не видел.

Comment: А нет, извините, действительно всё работает

Comment: А почему необходимо добавлять int? Почему он принимает в переменную тип str? Обычно при вводе числа в переменную вроде как передавался тип int?

Comment: Переменная же без типа, а пользователь вводит просто набор символов, и нужно интерпретатору объяснить, как именно интерпретировать введенную строку